# My new Western Digital Blue 2TB shows "Reboot and Select Proper Boot Device or Insert Boot Media in Selected Boot Device and Press a Key" error

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, sata

I just got my new Western Digital Blue 2TB 3D NANDA SATA 3.0 SSD but whenever I tried to run the PC into the Windows login screen, it always shows the terminal which reads "Reboot and Select Proper Boot Device or Insert Boot Media in Selected Boot Device and Press a Key." I then shut down the PC, go into the BIOS Settings and change the first Boot Priority and the Boot Override to my SSD. I checked several times to see if I had selected the correct SSD and tried to run it again. My brother incorrectly installed the SSD frame by taping it onto the actual PC rather than screwing it onto the PC, but I don't think this is the cause because all of the cables are correctly connected. There are two slots inside the SSD which you have to connect the cables to. Both are easily recognizable by the L shape which is on the cable. All I know is that the smaller cord connects the the Memory and the larger cord connects to the Power Supply. My brother taped the original SSD to the PC after screwing everything back onto the frame and plugging the cables back in and the original SSD worked perfectly. One thing my brother told me was that I many need to install windows onto the SSD. I don't know if this is true or not so I cannot be sure. Please leave me suggestions so I can finally use my SSD!

Answer (score 1):

Your brother is correct.
You have an empty SSD. There is nothing on it. That is how they come out of the packaging.
So your computer is very helpfully telling you to install an operating system (like Windows) on it so it becomes a proper boot device.

Normally, at this point, you would install the new SSD side by side with the old drive.
Then you use disk-cloning software (which isn't part of Windows, but often comes together with the new SSD for this purpose) to copy the old drive content to the new SSD.
Then you can remove the old drive and boot from the new SSD.
(Or you leave the old drive in there and re-format it for use as a data-drive.)

This cloning of the disk was apparently not done.